# Testing a steganalysis technique on realistic data

Tags: steganography

I'm developing a new image steganalysis technique, and I'd like to test how effective it is in practice.  How could I do this?  Are there such things as standard "test vectors" for steganalysis?

Comment: This isn't a cryptography question. Perhaps security.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Requests for reference recommendations are off-topic here. For details, see: [Do we want “literature recommendations” and similar “list/subjective questions”?](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1/do-we-want-literature-recommendations-and-similar-list-subjective-questions)

Comment: I'm not sure if this question really qualifies as a "reference recommendation" in the sense discussed at the meta post @e-sushi linked to. Even if it does, though, rephrasing it e.g. as "_How can I test the effectiveness of my new image steganalysis technique on realistic data?_" should make it on topic here.

Comment: @Layla: I just tried to do that myself, but feel free to change anything you want (especially if you feel I introduced any inaccuracies).  It's your question, after all.

Comment: Testing a new CSPRNG's output with existing randomness tests is next to pointless in order to show the goodness of the CSPRNG (tests can only detect some very bad CSPRNG, and _some_ implementation errors). Similarly, testing a steganalysis technique with existing test data (not designed with knowledge of the steganalysis technique) will not be a good demonstration of the virtues of the new techniques.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there such things as standard "test vectors" for steganalysis?

Not that I am aware of.

> How could I do this?

Your best bet would be to look for steganographic systems that are out there (either software or a paper describing it). Implement those systems and see how your steganalysis method works. Then you can implement other steganalysis methods from the literature and compare how well yours does vs those.